# XAML resource naming convention

Tags: xaml, naming-conventions

We are deciding if we should standardize on `camelCase` or `PascalCase` for XAML resource names.

Does anybody know if one style is usually favored over the other?

Does Microsoft have any convention for this?

For the record, we use `camelCase` for fields (that includes WPF controls, in the very few cases where they are named)

To avoid religious arguments: I'm not looking for "*this approach is BETTER than the other because...*" responses. A good answer would include links to reference material and/or statistics.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the `x:Name` attribute, you should use camel casing, as this generally results in a field being created behind the scenes. Microsoft, doesn't really follow this though in their default Styles, as control templates are one exception where a backing field is not created.

For the `x:Key` attribute, I've only ever seen pascal casing used. This includes in Microsoft's [default Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx).

Comment: I always use PascalCasing for x:Keys.  Mostly because I'm doing something like `<t:HerpDerpConverter x:Key="HerpDerpConverter" />`.  Its always easier to have a key be the type name in situations like this, so it is always easy to remember the key name for a particular resource.

Comment: Except MS naming guidelines for fields is camel casing preceded by an underscore.

Comment: @Jeff - Where is your source? The guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx) states "The field-naming guidelines apply to static public and protected fields. Internal and private fields are not covered by guidelines".

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected.  It's the default behavior in ReSharper which I always took to be a programmatic implementation of the Framework Design Guidelines.  Annoying, I sort of wish they would include it but I certainly understand why they opted not to.